# Подзапрос select и join

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, hql, hive

Пишу запрос, суть которого в селекте 2 полей из одной таблицы, и джоин с полем другой таблицы.

Но выпадает ошибка:

> Error while compiling statement: failed: parseexception line 3:0
>   cannot recognize input near ‘where’ ‘day’ ‘=‘ in subquery source

```
 Select prex_cr_id 
 from cx_ext_m 
     Full join (select rscr_cr_account_number from cr_res_m) 
 Where day = 20171005 
     and prex_cr_product_type = ‘RC’
```

Comment: Какая ошибка хоть?

Comment: Error while compiling statement: failed: parseexception line 3:0 cannot recognize input near ‘where’ ‘day’ ‘=‘ in subquery source

Comment: Начать с того, что mysql не поддерживает full join.

Дату следует заключать в кавычки - '20171005'.

Подзапрос в предложении from должен иметь имя.

Comment: Это не совсем SQL, а HQL

Answer (score 1):

1. У вас неправильный синтаксис. Вы соединяете 2 таблицы, `full join` позволяет оставить пустые поля, по которым не произошло соединения. Но после каждого соединения (`left join`, `right join`, `full join`, `inner join`) нужно указать, [по каким полям](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp) вы соединяете.

Например:

```
select *
from table1 full join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```

2. Не `‘RC’`, a `'RC'`. Если вы хотите показать равенство к текстовому значению, то текстовое значение заключается в одинарные апострофы.